# How to apply org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention plugin to custom gradle distribution?

Tags: gradle

We have hundreds of gradle projects using toolchains sdk automatic download on gradle 7.6.2 accross our organisation.
We also have a custom gradle distribution that we provide to all the teams.

Gradle 8 Upgrade instructions says

> [Using automatic toolchain downloading without having a repository configured](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#using_automatic_toolchain_downloading_without_having_a_repository_configured)
> Automatic toolchain downloading without explicitly providing repositories to use is no longer supported. See [user manual](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/toolchains.html#sub:download_repositories) for more information.

We don't want to force tens of teams to have to manually add

```
plugins {
    id 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention' version '0.7.0'
}
```

to hundreds of settings.gradle files and to have to manage the update of the version.
Since we'll already provide a custom gradle distribution for gradle 8.3 and since it contains an init.gradle script to setup some global variables. We would like to apply the convention in the init.gradle.

I tried unsuccessfully to apply *org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention* in our init.gradle
I also tried applying the plugin through its class name directly.
I searched the internet and read gradle code.

I managed to add *foojay-resolver-0.7.0.jar* inside the distribution gradle-8.3/lib/plugins directory.

Once the wrapper runs I can see it in ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/our-distribution-dir/generated-cache-dir/gradle-8.3/lib/plugins alongside gradle-plugins-8.3.jar

I'm pretty sure there is a way to achieve this. I just haven't found it.

When I try with class name

```
settingsEvaluated { settings ->
    settings.pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url repoUrl
            }
        }
    }

    settings.apply plugin: 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay.FoojayToolchainsConventionPlugin'
}

I get

> Could not get unknown property 'org' for build of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
```

When I try with plugin id

```
settingsEvaluated { settings ->
    settings.pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url repoUrl
            }
        }
    }

    settings.apply plugin: 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention'
}
```

I get

> Plugin with id 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention' not found.

Thanks in advance